# Java JTextField cannot be updated

Tags: java, swing

when I run the following code, I have problem in the level of the `TextField`. It is not updated during the process. **Only** when all the calculations was made, it will be updated completely at once.

```
System.out.println("Start....!!");
MyJTextField.setText("Start....!!"); 

MyJTextField.setText("Result1 is calculated now….”); 
/* here : Connect a DataBase and Make Calculations of the Var : Result1 */
System.out.println(Result1); 

MyJTextField.setText("Result2 is calculated now….”); 
/* here : Connect a DataBase and Make Calculations of the Var : Result2 */
System.out.println(Result2); 

MyJTextField.setText("Result3 is calculated now….”); 
/* here : Connect a DataBase and Make Calculations of the Var : Result3 */
System.out.println(Result3); 

// and so ….
```

Running the code will make the following :

- Prints in the consol : Start….!!
- Calculates Result1
- Prints in the consol the value of Result1
- Calculates Result2
- Prints in the console the value of Result2
- Calculates Result3
- Prints in the console the value of Result3

After that it updates `MyJTextField` completely at once.

Thanks a lot for any useful help.

Answer (score 2):

I'd call all Swing UI-related methods inside an anonymous `java.lang.Runnable` class and run it by passing it to  `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable runnable)`. This ensures that the UI operations called inside of the Runnable's `run()` method will be called on the EDT (event dispatching thread). Never run Swing operations on e.g. the same thread that does for example longer running computations. See code below...

```
// non-ui thread
System.out.println("Start....!!");

// call on ui-thread (event dispatching thread)
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        MyJTextField.setText("Start....!!"); 
        MyJTextField.setText("Result1 is calculated now….”); 
    }
}

// non ui-thread again...
/* here : Connect a DataBase and Make Calculations of the Var : Result1 */
System.out.println(Result1); 

// call on ui-thread again (event dispatching thread)
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        MyJTextField.setText("Result2 is calculated now….”); 
    }
}

// and so ….
```

shorter version using lambdas (Java8+):

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> MyJTextField.setText("Result2 is calculated now….”));
```

Comment: The problem is that the code is already running on the EDT. This answer does not specifically state that the long running task must be moved to a separate Thread before you start adding the invokeLater() logic. While this is addressed in the comments of the code, it is not apparent from the verbal description what the problem is.

Comment: it DOES NOT WORK, unfortunately ...
Also, i did not understand the last 2 lines ...
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java swing library, then the UI is rendered by a specific thread, meaning a thread update the UI at a different time the calculation are made from the main thread.

You should try to use the `validate()` or `repaint()` methods over Swing components to update them properly as:

```
MyJTextField.setText("Result1 is calculated now….”); 
MyJTextField.validate();
// or MyJTextField.repaint();
```

Comment: (1-) You do not need to invoke validate() or repaint(). Swing components will automatically invoike revalidate() and repaint() on themselves when a property of the component is changed.

Answer (score 0):

> it will be updated completely at once.

All the code is executing on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`, so the GUI can only repaint itself once the processing is finished.

If you have a long running task, then you need to execute that task on a separate `Thread` so you don't block he `EDT` and the GUI is able to repaint itself.

One way to do this is to use a `SwingWorker`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information about the EDT and how to use a `SwingWorker`.

If you want to update the GUI while the database access is being done you can then "publish" the updates. This will make sure the GUI is updated on the EDT.

Comment: it seems Perfect ...
Can you please write a sample code showing how to re-write my code ???
Many thanks...

Comment: The tutorial has a working example. You move your code to the SwingWorker. Or you create a Thread an move all your code to the run() method of the Thread (Tommy showed you the code for this approach). We are not here to write the code for you.